# $.Deferred.resolve is "not a function" in Firefox event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-deferred, dom-events

When I pass a jQuery deferred object to a window event handler in a sandboxed Greasemonkey script under Firefox, for some reason the `resolve` function is undefined.

Consider the following test userscript, which must be run on a page that already has jQuery loaded (this is as minimal as I could get it):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Deferred Event Test
// @namespace   jasonc
// @description Deferred Event Test
// @include     /https?:\/\/*/
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

// Event listener calls ev.detail.deferred.resolve().
window.addEventListener('test-event-1234', function (ev) {
  try {
    console.log(ev.detail.deferred);
    console.log(ev.detail.deferred.resolve);
    ev.detail.deferred.resolve(42);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});

function runTest ($) {

  // Test resolve directly.
  $.Deferred(function (def) {
    def.resolve(99);
  }).then(function (v) {
    console.log(`resolved: ${v}`);
  });

  // Test through event listener.
  $.Deferred(function (def) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-event-1234', { detail: {
      deferred: def
    }}));
  }).then(function (v) {
    console.log(`resolved: ${v}`);
  });

}

// Inject script into page and run it.
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.textContent = `(${runTest.toString()})(window.jQuery)`;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Of note:

- Runs at `document-idle`, so jQuery is already available.
- Has a non-`none` grant, so that it's sandboxed.
- Injects the `runTest` function into the page and runs it from there.

What this is *supposed* to do is dispatch the "test-event-1234" with `ev.detail.deferred` set to a jQuery deferred object, then wait for the event listener to resolve it. However, it outputs the following in the console instead:

```
resolved: 99

Object { resolve: Deferred/</e[f[0]](), resolveWith: fireWith(), 
         reject: Deferred/</e[f[0]](), rejectWith: fireWith(), 
         notify: Deferred/</e[f[0]](), notifyWith: fireWith(), 
         state: state(), always: always(), then: then(),
         promise: promise(), 4 more… } 

undefined

TypeError: ev.detail.deferred.resolve is not a function
Stack trace:
    // indicates the resolve() call in the event listener
```

The "resolved: 99" is the output of the direct (no event listener) test, showing that `resolve()` does indeed exist at that point.

The next line of output is the `console.log(ev.detail.deferred)` in the event handler, which shows that `resolve` exists at some point (and at least confirms I passed the correct object to the event handler), but the `console.log(ev.detailed.deferred.resolve)` (which I added after [Kevin B's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592746/deferred-resolve-is-not-a-function-in-firefox-event-listener#comment76173454_44592746), so as not to be misled by async console output issues) shows `undefined`.

And then, the call fails, stating that `ev.detail.deferred.resolve` is not a function.

The following things make this work fine:

- Running it on Chrome (Tampermonkey), no issue.
- Changing the grant to `@grant none` so that it isn't sandboxed.

What is going on here? I've been staring at this for a while and I'm pretty confident there aren't any typos. I can't figure out why it says `resolve` is undefined, especially given that the "direct" test right before it called `resolve` with no issues. Is there a way to make this work?

---

### Additional Tests

Some tests suggested in a (removed) comment. So far all of these yield the same results as above:

Delay before creating deferred object:

```
  // Test with delay #1
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $.Deferred(function (def) {
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-event-1234', { detail: {
       deferred: def
      }}));
    }).then(function (v) {
      console.log(`resolved: ${v}`);
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Delay before dispatching event:

```
  // Test with delay #2
  $.Deferred(function (def) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-event-1234', { detail: {
        deferred: def
      }}));
    }, 2000);
  }).then(function (v) {
    console.log(`resolved: ${v}`);
  });
```

Delay in event before calling `resolve`:

```
// Event listener calls ev.detail.deferred.resolve() after a delay.
window.addEventListener('test-event-delayed-1234', function (ev) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    try {
      console.log(ev.detail.deferred.resolve);
      ev.detail.deferred.resolve(42);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, ev.detail.timeout);
});

... then, elswhere: ...

  // Test with delay #3
  $.Deferred(function (def) {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-event-delayed-1234', { detail: {
      deferred: def,
      timeout: 3000
    }}));
  }).then(function (v) {
    console.log(`resolved: ${v}`);
  });
```

Comment: To rule out console.log weirdness, log the property directly: `console.log(ev.detail.deferred.resolve);`

Comment: @KevinB Oh strange, when I do that it says `undefined`. What is going on here? Why would it be undefined and ... why is the console output misleading?

Comment: The console output is resolved at the time you expand it, not the time it is logged. So what you have is an async problem or a race condition.

Comment: `Deferred/</e[f[0]]()` looks really weird. What console are you using, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Given the things you stated that make it work, I suspect that you cannot pass functions between the realms.

Comment: @Bergi Just the [Firefox dev tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgXFL.png). I think you're right about the functions. I tried a test just passing a function in `detail`, and also passing a function in another object in `detail`, and ran into the same issues.

Comment: Ok, this *is* a weird representation of that not-so-really-a-callable-function object. You might want to report it as a bug to the devtools.